# Log accuracy metric while training a tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

What's the simplest way to print accuracy metrics along with the loss when training a pre-canned estimator?

Most tutorials and documentations seem to address the issue of when you're creating a custom estimator -- which seems overkill if the intention is to use one of the available ones.

tf.contrib.learn had a few (now deprecated) Monitor hooks. TF now suggests using the hook API, but it appears that it doesn't actually come with anything that can utilize the labels and predictions to generate an accuracy number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, metric_fn)` ([doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/add_metrics))? It takes an initialized estimator (can be pre-canned) and adds to it the metrics defined by `metric_fn`.

Usage Example:

```python
def custom_metric(labels, predictions):
    # This function will be called by the Estimator, passing its predictions.
    # Let's suppose you want to add the "mean" metric...

    # Accessing the class predictions (careful, the key name may change from one canned Estimator to another)
    predicted_classes = predictions["class_ids"]  

    # Defining the metric (value and update tensors):
    custom_metric = tf.metrics.mean(labels, predicted_classes, name="custom_metric")

    # Returning as a dict:
    return {"custom_metric": custom_metric}

# Initializing your canned Estimator:
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=columns_feat, hidden_units=[10, 10], n_classes=NUM_CLASSES)

# Adding your custom metrics:
classifier = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(classifier, custom_metric)

# Training/Evaluating:
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO) # Just to have some logs to display for demonstration

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda:your_train_dataset_function(),
                                    max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS)
eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda:your_test_dataset_function(),
                                steps=EVAL_STEPS,
                                start_delay_secs=EVAL_DELAY,
                                throttle_secs=EVAL_INTERVAL)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Logs:

```
...
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [20/200]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [40/200]
...
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [200/200]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2018-04-19-09:23:03
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1: accuracy = 0.5668, average_loss = 0.951766, custom_metric = 1.2442, global_step = 1, loss = 95.1766
...
```

As you can see, the `custom_metric` is returned along the default metrics and loss.

Comment: I think OP wants a solution working for premade estimators for which you are not supposed to change the `model_fn` directly. Therefore, this might not be the desired answer.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that even though the example on Github showcases a custom classifier, the use of hooks as shown in the extracted lines would work with any premade estimators, as they all implement `train(...)`,  `evaluate(...)`,  `predict(...)` with the `hooks` parameter.

Comment: A quick thought is the `logging_hook` needs accuracy being computed in `model_fn` and needs the name of accuracy. Your extracted line 185 is from within `model_fn` which is going to be out of control for premade estimators. Now what I'm not sure is whether there are counterparts in premade estimators which can be used.

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right. I was assuming from OP's post that s*he had somehow got access to the prediction tensor. I've updated my post with hopefully a clearer answer making use of `tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics`.

Comment: Great answer! That seems to be the correct solution. Really learned a new thing, `tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics`. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this is a super helpful answer. I'm curious - have you used this approach for a custom estimator too? Why wouldn't that be recommended vs what most tutorials follow today?

Comment: No, I actually never use pre-canned estimators myself - I actually discovered this approach while trying to correct my original answer. Why it isn't more prevalent is a good question...

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer of @Aldream you can also use the [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) to see some graphics of the `custom_metric`. To do that, add it to a TensorFlow summary like this:

```
tf.summary.scalar('custom_metric', custom_metric)
```

The cool thing when you use the `tf.estimator.Estimator` is that you don't need to add the summaries to a `FileWriter`, since it's done automatically (merging and saving them every 100 steps by default).

In order to see the TensorBoard you need to open a new terminal and type:

```
tensorboard --logdir={$MODEL_DIR}
```

After that you will be able to see the graphics in your browser at `localhost:6006`.